# How to dynamically generate DIV above an image

Tags: javascript, css

I have some scanned news paper and i want to dynamically generate div above the image. So when users click on specific DIV they are redirected to detail of that news.
How is it possible ?
One way of doing is to create Absoulute positioned div in front of the Image. But i dont want to create DIV for all scanned images. I am searching for some dynamic way. Plus! I am not looking for image Maps.

Example : http://www.express.com.pk/epaper/
This is an e-paper and they are using a single image on their background. Of course they are not creating static html pages each day and redefine their div positions

Edit: For my case i found my solution using Facebook Like Tagging jQuery Plugin.

Comment: Show the HTML you're starting with.

Comment: <image src="newspaper1.jpg" width="900" height="1200"/>

Comment: I usually let a server-sided language handle this sort of thing (if that is a possibility). Despite what a multitude of answerers will inevitably suggest, you shouldn't rely on a Javascript/JS framework to insert the HTML for you.

Comment: Looking at the page it seems they _do_ redefine the image/div map each day.

Answer (score 0):

Have one absolutely positioned `<div>` and move it around to whatever image is focused. Change the click effect of the `div` accordingly.

Comment: example http://www.express.com.pk/epaper/ is this e-paper the bacground image is one single image. And i believe that they are not creating static HTML page each day

Answer (score 0):

You will have a div containing the image, like this:

```
<div id="imageDiv">
    <img ... />
</div>
```

And you will use jquery to create a div before the img in your click event:

```
$("#imageDiv").prepend("<div>created div before image</div>");
```

Comment: in my case there are about 300 scanned images. And in each image i have to define around 10 - 15 clickable div in front of the image. I am searching a way to dynamically create it not to write html/css for 300 images

Comment: This 10-15 cliclable divs will be always the same to all 300 images?

Comment: no. I need some kind of System WHERE these 10-15 can be redefined for each images

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, for a variable layout such as a newspaper image, absolutely positioned divs are probably your best bet.

In this case, Javascript would likely cause more problems than it would solve: it isn't a necessity for what you want to achieve, and people with Javascript disabled will be unable to use your site.

One other possibility is to use a server-sided language to read a xml file that says where the divs should be placed over an image. This would allow for a dynamic html page, as only a xml (or similar) file would need to be altered to change content.

I can generate an example if you're interested in this solution.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly easier way may be to use an image map. [Here's a good resource with working examples](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_map.asp).